# port install of log4cxx failes on Mac osx 10.6

Tags: ros, installation, log4cxx, macos-snowleopard, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: Rosdep install failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in 
pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.20', 'rosinstall')
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 489, in run_script

File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1214, in run_script
self.egg_info = os.path.join(path, 'EGG-INFO')
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.20-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 599, in

File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.20-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 590, in rosinstall_main

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 462, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /Users/brianriviere/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11114/port-install-of-log4cxx-failes-on-mac-osx-10.6/) by [brian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1041/brian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you maybe give more info on the context on which u get this

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-09-07**:
If Macports can't build log4cxx, that's a MacPorts problem (and they provide a suggestion right there in the error message you posted).

**Comment by [brian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1041/brian/) on 2011-09-05**:
Right now it is failing failing to install log4cxx using:

sudo port install log4cxx

To report a bug, see http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Failed to install log4cxx!
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: Rosdep install failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
Fi